# Laravel 5.4 - Use Controller Route in javascript function

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, datatables

I have a table (datatables) and I have an edit icon and I want to call a route with the parameter.

My function is currently is

```
function editItem(id)
    {
        //alert(id);
    }
```

What I want to do is to call

```
UsersController@editItem
```

and also pass the id to the controller.

I am a little stuck!

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing server-side logic with client-side logic. The controller method you want to call is a server-side component that doesn't exist in client-side logic.

You should pass the route definition to JS and call this url using AJAX (jquery or axios are your friends) and read the response from the server in an asynchronous way.

I try to explain with some example code:

```
//routes.php
Route::get('/edit', [
  'uses' => 'UsersController@editItem',
  'as' => 'edit-item'
]);

//blade file
<script>
window.routes = {
  editItem: "{{ route('edit-item') }}",
}
function editItem(id)
{
  $.post(window.routes.editItem, { id: id }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}    
</script>
```

Comment: I am a little confused as I wish to take the user to the edit page which will be defined in the contoller function.

Comment: So you need to redirect user to the route. You should pass route from PHP to Javascript and then ```document.location = window.routes.editItem```

Comment: Could you b e kind enough to give me some example code. I really appreciate your help.